# Kafka Consumer: What does it mean to "hash into queues"?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In the Javadoc for [`KafkaConsumer`](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html), under the section `2. Decouple Consumption and Processing`, it is stated as follows:

> There are many possible variations on [the threading approach where there is one or more consumers that do all data consumption, and hand off `ConsumerRecords` instances to a blocking queue of processor threads]. For example each processor thread can have its own queue, and the consumer threads can **hash into these queues** using the TopicPartition to ensure in-order consumption and simplify commit.

Question:

What does it mean for the consumer threads to *hash into [the] queues*? And how does that ensure in-order consumption and simplify commit?